# Recommended floor protection when assembling Ikea furniture?

Tags: hardwood-floor, protection

I'm completely new to DIY home assembly, but I'm planning to buy some Ikea furniture to furnish an apartment I just rented.

I've read online that I should protect the floor (hardwood) when assembling the furniture, and although some recommend using the boxes it came with, I'd like to ensure I'm using proper protection.

I've searched around a bit and read [What should I use to protect and cover my floors during construction?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/21261/what-should-i-use-to-protect-and-cover-my-floors-during-construction), and it looks like Ram Board is a pretty good option, but I'd like to hear about any other alternatives.

Since this is temporary and I'm just assembling a bed, table and drawers, I am looking for ***a cheaper option while still providing adequate protection***.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kudos for being such a diligent renter. The cardboard they come in is totally adequate. Depending on what you've got, you might even have a nice double layer workspace.